# Use variable to replace some constant Android API

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera

I'm developing a function checking `camera`if any

```
if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA) == false)
{
//do something
}
```

it's ok, but when put these codes into function with argument, it doesn't work

```
public boolean checkCameraDevice(String str)
    {
        if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.str) == false)
        {
```

so, how to implement `checkCameraDevice`function in order to I can pass `FEATURE_CAMERA`

```
checkCameraDevice("FEATURE_CAMERA")
```

Comment: Read this first http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c4/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA` refers to a constant field in `PackageManager` whose actual value is `"android.hardware.camera"`.
`FEATURE_CAMERA` is variable name and you can't call it by `PackageManager."FEATURE_CAMERA"` its totally wrong. If you want to call API `checkCameraDevice(str)` with String parameter pass `"android.hardware.camera"` instead of variable name.

Method Definition:

```
public boolean checkCameraDevice(String str)
{
    if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(str) == false)
    {
         //do something
    }
}
```

Method Call:

```
checkCameraDevice("android.hardware.camera");
```

or

```
checkCameraDevice(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);
```

Answer (score 2):

*You can not use `PackageManager.str` to get constants of `PackageManager`, if `str` is a variable.*

You need to pass constant value into parameter.

Use like this:

```
public boolean checkCameraDevice(String feature)
    {
        if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(feature) == false)
        {
```

and call as

```
checkCameraDevice(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);
```

Answer (score 1):

The constant value for `PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA` is `android.hardware.camera`.
You should call like this

```
checkCameraDevice("android.hardware.camera");
```

or simply call

```
checkCameraDevice(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);
```

and you can't call `PackageManager.str` where `str` is unavailable in `PackageManager`. You should directly use the string or else you can use the constant.